# How do I clear all ComboBoxes at once By looping through them?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, loops, combobox

I have about nine ComboBoxes on my form and each one is filtered according to the one that came before it, so when I change the value of the first ComboBox I need to clear the rest, is there any way to loop through all of them and clear each one?
I tried this:

```
private void Clear()
        {
            foreach (ComboBox cmb in Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
                cmb.Items.Clear();
        }
```

Comment: Filtered how? If you're using a filtered DataView of a DataTable, you can remove the filter. A `List<SomeType>`? Remove the LINQ Where/Select that ruled out some items. Otherwise, it depends on how your handling those collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmb.Items.Clear(); //this  removes the items 
cmb.ResetText(); //this clear text
```

Comment: I fixed it, forgot my ComboBoxes were in a groupbox so I just added it in front of Controls.ofType, thank you anyway